# How do I create dictionary functions for different languages in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm creating vocab lists for different language learning projects of mine in Google sheets. I'm familiar with the Google translate function and use it for one column of my vocab lists, but I would also like to create a function to add definitions in the target language, either using AI or that language's dictionary (https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ , duden.de , https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/ , etc). I've seen formulas that work for Merriam Webster or Oxford, but I haven't been able to work it out for other dictionaries. Note: I'm a linguist, not a coder.

I tried modifying formulas I found for oxford and merriam webster, but I'm definitely missing something. I also tried an AI app (PromptLoop) but I couldn't make that work either.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)